# Register a generic Validator using FluentValidation and Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, autofac, fluentvalidation

I have a generic class that handles different entities the same manner. I'm trying to implement a Validator in this generic class, the Validator type should change depending on the generic type. For example if the type is Person, the PersonValidator should get initialized. How is this possible using FluentValidation and Autofac? I've tried it using a generic BaseValidator but I cannot seem to register it correctly so the PersonValidator doesn't get called.

Generic class

```
var validator = new BaseValidator<TEntity>(); // TEntity = Person
await validator.ValidateAndThrowAsync(person);
```

BaseValidator

```
public class BaseValidator<TEntity> : AbstractValidator<TEntity>
{
}
```

PersonValidator

```
public class PersonValidator : BaseValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Autofac registrations that I've tried

```
 builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseValidator<>)).As(typeof(IValidator<>)).InstancePerDependency();
 builder.RegisterType<BaseValidator<Person>().As(typeof(IValidator<Person>)).InstancePerDependency();
 builder.RegisterType<PersonValidator>().As(typeof(IValidator<Person>)).InstancePerDependency();
 builder.RegisterType<PersonValidator>().As(typeof(BaseValidator<Person>)).InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: so long time but by any change you have found an answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `var validator = new BaseValidator<TEntity>();` You have to inject an `IValidator<Person>` in your ctor (or `IValidator<T>`).

Comment: any chance you can elaborate on that, not sure what you mean?

Comment: You should be more detailed with your answer, not just to erect two lines of text and expect everyone to understand what you mean